# Sorting a list of tuples by a certain element in a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tuples, sortedlist

```
def insert(key, value, D, hasher = hash):

    x = hash(key)
    key_value = (x, key, value)
    D.append(key_value)
    sorted(D, key = lambda x:x[0])
    return D

insert("swag", 100, D, hash)

insert("swg", 150, D, hash)

print(D)
```

this never seems to be sorted,

I want to sort the list via the x value

Comment: Didn't you mean to use `hasher(key)` rather than `hash(key)`. Otherwise you are hashing using the default hash function every time regardless of the provided argument.

Answer (score 4):

You are sorting the list and immediately throwing the sorted list away. Note that `sorted` returns a new list so you'll also need to *reassign* the sorted list to the name `D`.

```
...
return sorted(D, key=lambda x:x[0])
```

To sort in-place, use the *sort* method of the list: `D.sort`

```
def insert(key, value, D, hasher = hash):
    ...
    D.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Comment: Also, `key = lambda x:x[0]` is pretty pointless, as it will sort by `key[0]` anyways. This just removes the tie-breaker.

Comment: @ayydoe Then you may consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You've confused **sorted** and **sort**.  **sorted** is a function that leaves the original iterable alone, but *returns* a sorted item.  You didn't save that value.  Try this:

```
return sorted(D, key = lambda x:x[0])
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

```
def insert(key, value, D, hasher = hash):

    x = hash(key)
    key_value = (x, key, value)
    D.append(key_value)
    print D
    D.sort()
    return D


D = []
insert("swag", 100, D, hash)
insert("swg",  150, D, hash)
insert("loot", 200, D, hash)
insert("crud",  50, D, hash)

print(D)
```

Output:

```
[(-1840385907632881630, 'swag', 100)]
[(-1840385907632881630, 'swag', 100), (-369175422006790866, 'swg', 150)]
[(-1840385907632881630, 'swag', 100), (-369175422006790866, 'swg', 150), (5971043325587305850, 'loot', 200)]
[(-1840385907632881630, 'swag', 100), (-369175422006790866, 'swg', 150), (5971043325587305850, 'loot', 200), (5473401298224946764, 'crud', 50)]
[(-1840385907632881630, 'swag', 100), (-369175422006790866, 'swg', 150), (5473401298224946764, 'crud', 50), (5971043325587305850, 'loot', 200)]
```

Comment: I did that, and it still didn't work, it still gave this output

Comment: [(6465318664160753506, 'swag', 100), (-1220143650632114200, 'swg', 150)]

Comment: @ayydoe Please show *exactly* what you did. `sorted([(6465318664160753506, 'swag', 100), (-1220143650632114200, 'swg', 150)], key=lambda x:x[0])` returns `[(-1220143650632114200, 'swg', 150), (6465318664160753506, 'swag', 100)]`, as expected.